# Why is one Func valid and the other (almost identical) not

Tags: function, c#-3.0, delegates, anonymous-methods

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> _parseActions 
                                   = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>
    {
        { typeof(bool), value => {Convert.ToBoolean(value) ;}}
    };
```

The above gives an error

> Error 14 Not all code paths return a
>   value in lambda expression of type
>   'System.Func<string,object>'

However this below is ok.

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> _parseActions 
                                   = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>
    {
        { typeof(bool), value => Convert.ToBoolean(value) }
    };
```

I don't understand the difference between the two. I thought the extra braces in example1 are to allow us to use multiple lines in the anon function so why have they affected the meaning of the code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first uses a code block, which will only return a value if you use the `return` keyword:

```
value => { return Convert.ToBoolean(value); }
```

The second, being just an expression doesn't require an explicit `return`.

Comment: Yep, I posted the question, then looked at it for another ooooh 30 seconds before i realised my mistake :) cheers

Answer (score 2):

The first one you are not returning anything and you must explicitly return a value since you have a wrapped it, where the second one you are implicitly returning a value.

To fix it do

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> _parseActions = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> 
{ 
  { typeof(bool), value => { return Convert.ToBoolean(value) ;}} 
};
```